# rebase on top of rebased feature branch

Tags: git, rebase

I'm having some trouble with a rebase-driven feature development workflow. I'll explain with diagrams.

So let's say I'm working on a feature, so I branch from master at commit B. I have some work that isn't ready to be pushed to the PR, so I branch a subfeature.

```
A -> B -> C # master
     |
     D -> E # feature
          |
          F -> G # subfeature
```

Upstream work continues, and I need to update the PR, so I rebase the feature branch:

```
$ git checkout feature
$ git rebase master

A -> B -> C # master
     |    |
     |    D' -> E' # feature
     |
     D -> E
          |
          F -> G # subfeature
```

Let's assume the merge conflicts are minor and don't really affect the work in commits F and G. Now, I want to rebase the subfeature branch as well. If I just run `git checkout subfeature && git rebase feature`, it doesn't really work because the common ancestor of those is B. The structure I want is:

```
A -> B -> C # master
          |
          D' -> E' # feature
                |
                F' -> G' # subfeature
```

...but I don't know how to achieve it, without going through the entire `git rebase master` and re-resolving the merge conflicts that I already did while rebasing `feature`. Is it possible?

Comment: Is there a reason rebasing subfeature on top of feature would not work?

Comment: @Casey I tried that, as I said -- I think the issue is that the common commits between `feature` and `subfeature` (D and E) are no longer part of `feature`. So the rebase contains a lot more commits than I would expect (it's trying to put D and E back in, plus D' and E', along with C, F, G). It's also possible I completely misinterpreted the output.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I understand what you mean now.  Why don't you do an interactive rebase and then skip all the common commits?

Comment: after checking out subfeature use `git rebase --onto feature E`

Comment: @AndrewC You should make an answer, you have the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to `cherry-pick` everything from `subfeature` fork into the new `feature` branch.

```
# Create a temporary branch and point it to 'feature' branch
git checkout feature
git checkout -b foo

# Now replay subfeature revisions
git cherry-pick E..G

# Verify that 'foo' looks correct and cleanup
git branch -D subfeature
git branch -m subfeature
```

Notice that you start with the revision that you don't want to pick, i.e. `E`

I used this trick quite often.

Note that you will need to use 'force' to push 'subfeature' to remote if it has already been published.

Comment: This is basically a more tedious way of doing an interactive rebase.